# dplyr: do on a subset of groups

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a date frame `df` with an Id variable. I can use `group_by(Id)` to group the data  by this `Id` and then perform usual calculation with `summarise` or `do`.

Now I'd like to plot some things with ggplot2 but say on the first five groups of `df` while `do` apply the function to each group.

What should I do ? I can think using `id = unique(df$Id)` and then `df %>% filter(Id=id[i])` for some `i` but I think there is a more direct way.

MWE:

```
df = data.frame(Value=1:10, Id=rep(c('a', 'b'), each = 5)) %>% group_by(Id)
> df
   Value Id
1      1  a
2      2  a
3      3  a
4      4  a
5      5  a
6      6  b
7      7  b
8      8  b
9      9  b
10    10  b
```

Then I'd like to plot for instance:

```
df %>% filter(Id=='a') %>% ggplot(aes(x=Value, y=Value)) + geom_line()
```

but without having to specify the value of the filter, like if I could write "apply to first group".

Comment: Care to share some data, expected output, etc?

Comment: `filter` first? Hard to tell without a concrete example.

Comment: Perhaps `df %>% filter(Id %in% unique(Id)[1:5]) %>% .....`?

Comment: @Axeman good trick, works with `df %>% filter(Id==unique(df$Id)[i]) %>%  ...` but grouping is useless then.

Comment: assign ids to the groups using `group_indices()`, then use `top_n()` maybe?

Comment: Maybe also `df %>% filter(Id==levels(!!(groups(.)[[1]]))[1])` (dplyr 0.6), although this looks a bit esoteric. (It's 1. get the grouping variables, 2. take the first one, 3. unquote it, get the levels of it, 4. take the first one)

Comment: This can't really be answered without a clear example, particularly for what you mean by: "I'd like to plot some things with ggplot2 but say on the first five groups of df while `do` apply the function to each group."